# getting json data jquery with .get

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<script> 
      $.get("url", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      var json = JSON.stringify(data);
      });
 // I would like to use **json** variable here
</script>
```

Hey, 
I would like to **get** **data** from **url**. I can get the JSON file and stringify it to **json** variable. But I have some struggles when I 'm trying to use **json** variable. Because, it is local variable. 
Also,

```
 <script> 
     var json = "";
     $.get("url", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     json = JSON.stringify(data);
     });
 // I would like to use **json** variable here
</script>
```

when I am trying to use **json** as a global variable, even I can not stringify **data** to it.

*Question : How can I solve my problem?*

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: many people get confused about what json is...it's a string data transer format. You don't work with json in javascript...you were with the objects and arrays it represents once it is converted. So in most requests you would not stringify the data, you do totally the opposite

Comment: Are you getting data as JSON format?

Comment: If your are to stringify JSON object, it will be converted as string. I don't see an issue in the code snippet as well. What is exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I have struggles to use "data" (JSON data) out of getJSON. I can get the "data" from "url" but I could not to use is out of .get or .getJSON

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use your JSON data when it is available by putting the dependent code in a callback or a promise:

```
$.getJSON("url").then(function(data) {
  // json is already parsed here
  // put json dependent code here
});
```

You could also put your application logic in a function (assuming it's depending on the JSON data) and use that as your callback:

```
function initialize(data) {
   // all of your data dependent logic here
}

$.getJSON("url").then(initialize);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But the thing is, I have struggles to use "data" (JSON data) out of getJSON. I can get the "data" from "url" but I could not to use is out of .get or .getJSON

Comment: I understand, my advice is that this approach will not work very well. You should alter your program's structure to put code that is dependent on the json data into callback. I'll update my answer with another example